# Changing a wordpress user to an admin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set up a local copy of a production Wordpress blog. On production, I am a user but not an admin, so I am trying to change myself to an admin locally. I was following the directions on [this](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database) blog post to make myself an admin, so I performed the following SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(376, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');
INSERT INTO usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(376, 'wp_user_level', 10);
```

Then I cleared my browser cookies and logged in again, but when I tried to navigate to `http://localhost/wp-admin` I still got "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." I even went so far as to delete my APC cache files and reload Nginx and PHP-FPM, which also didn't change anything. Does anyone know of anything else to try?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To set the `capabilities` and `user_level` your `meta_key` value needs to match your database prefix. By default this is `wp_` (resulting in `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level`) however it would be different in your case as you don't have a prefix. The proper `capabilities` value is `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`.

```
-- delete any existing values for this user
DELETE FROM usermeta WHERE user_id=376 AND (meta_key LIKE '%capabilities' OR meta_key LIKE '%user_level')
-- insert the capabilities and user_level for user_id 376
INSERT INTO usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(376, 'capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');
INSERT INTO usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(376, 'user_level', 10);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to change assign a User to the Admin Role in WordPress using MySQL statements:

```
-- Look at the field called "id" in the result set
---
select * from wp_users
where user_login = 'WORDPRESS_USERNAME_GOES_HERE';

-- Substitute the above "id" value in the "user_id" field below.
-- This is an integer value so do not use quotes around it
-- For example if the above "id" is the value 10 then the resulting line would be: where user_id = 10
-- 
update wp_usermeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'
where user_id = USER_ID_GOES_HERE
and meta_key = 'wp_capabilities';

-- Lastly execute this statement remembering to substitute the same "id" value
update wp_usermeta
set meta_value = '10'
where user_id = USER_ID_GOES_HERE
and meta_key = 'wp_user_level';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have already have your username and password then you just need to update capability and role into database.

Go to wp_user table and locate your ID from there i.e. in my case its 2. And then go to wp_usermeta and look for meta_key = wp_capabilities and user_id - 2. Edit that row and change meta_value to

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}.
```

Again go for meta_key = wp_user_level and user_id = 2. Edit that row and change meta_value to 10. Don't change other rows where user_id is not your own.

See my wp_users table.
[image: Look for the ID]

See my wp_usermeta table.
[image: Look for capabilities and roles]

Two queries will be fired something like these:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = '10' WHERE `wp_usermeta`.`umeta_id` =27;

UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}' WHERE `wp_usermeta`.`umeta_id` =26;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I noticed that the table in your example is called wp_usermeta and my table is just called usermeta. Does that make a difference? Edit: Forgot to mention that I have already tried what you are suggesting.

Comment: No. My wordpress is being setup with prefix wp_. Well in your case its not.

Comment: It does matter, the `meta_key` has to match your prefix, so if you are using `wp_` then it would be `wp_capabilities`... I have never had an empty prefix, but it would presumably just be `capabilities` and `user_level` for the `meta_key`