# Rename table prefix in phpmyadmin if does not begin with wp_ but contains it

Tags: database, wordpress

I would like to rename the prefix for WordPress database. I understand that the way to do this is to replace the `wp_` prefix in the phpmyadmin tables.

The fields that begin with wp_ are easy to find and replace. Do I need to change fields that contain `_wp_` within them? For example:

Do I need to replace the wp_ in the below?

```
dismissed_wp_pointers
```

or

```
_wp_attached_file_wp_pointers
```

.
**EDIT**

Notice that in addition to replacing "table" prefixes, I would also update "rows" **within** a table. For example, within the table `wp_usermeta` I must replace a few rows such as `wp_capabilities` 
Within `wp_usermeta` table there is a row called

```
dismissed_wp_pointers
```

Am I suppose to replace the wp_ in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix refers to TABLE names (e.g. `wp_commentmeta`), and keys that are PREFIXED within tables.

This is useful for [multiple blogs that share the same database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database).

See more about [Database Table Prefixes in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Database_Table_Prefix).

If you're changing this prefix, you only need to update table names and keys in tables that are PREFIXED (i.e. begin with) `wp_`. These are likely in the Options and UserMeta tables.

Comment: @mevius There are tutorials that say to update prefixes of "rows" within certain tables also. Could you address the additional info in my "Edit" above?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update all database tables that begin with `wp_` to use your new prefix. This prefix should be set in `wp-config.php`. You will also need to update all of the `meta_key` in the `usermeta` table and `option_name` in the `options` table fir values that contain your previous prefix to use the new one.

Update PREFIX_options table option_name values

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PREFIX_options` 
WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%wp_%'
```

Update PREFIX_usermeta table meta_key values

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PREFIX_usermeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` 
LIKE '%wp_%'
```

See [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096115/1427161) for an example of why it is important to update these values (the `$wpdb->prefix . "capabilities"` key in this case).

Comment: Just to be extra clear. I must update stuff that BEGINS with wp_ therefore I do NOT replace the wp_ within `dismissed_wp_pointers` (which is a meta_key row inside the `wp_usermeta` table)

Comment: That is likely, but not necessarily guaranteed - anything can use `$wpdb->prefix` as part of a key. I would search your install base to see where that value is coming from to determine if you need to update the key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should **not** change `dismissed_update_core`'s name.

After reading doublesharp's comment, I made a search through the Wordpress's code and found that `dismissed_update_core` was hardcoded, unlike `wp_user_level` for instance. Prefixed names use `$wpdb->get_blog_prefix()` (which returns `base_prefix` for single blog Wordpress sites) or `$wpdb->prefix` that you can lookup in the source code.

You'll find the hardcoded `dismissed_update_core` in `wp-admin\includes\ajax-actions.php` and `wp-admin\includes\class-wp-internal-pointers.php`.